# MDL floating label textfields: changing its colour

Tags: html, colors, textfield, material-design-lite

At the moment, the textfield in my HTML file is blue. Is there a way to make it red instead? Thanks.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Textfield Demo</title>
  <!-- Import MDL libraries -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue-red.min.css"/>
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
          <div class="mdl-cell--10-col" style="text-align:center; height:60vh">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-bar">
              <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-bar">Text...</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your CSS as below,

```
   .is-focused {
      color: #FD5155 !important;
   }
   .mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label, .mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-dirty .mdl-textfield__label, .mdl-textfield--floating-label.has-placeholder .mdl-textfield__label {
      color: #FD5155 !important;
   }
   .mdl-textfield__input {
      border-color: #FD5155 !important;
   }
```

Comment: The underline that shows up when you click on it is still blue. Besides, is it possible to have it the same red as the button?

Comment: Sure @KenEly Copy the CSS file in your project directory instead and update the color codes accordingly

Comment: Here's the red color code of your button `#fd5155`
You'll have to replace the RGB code `rgb(33,150,243)` with the red color code